# Updating Value using key of the dictionary

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am using a `Dictionary` in VB.NET Windows application.

I have added several values in a `Dictionary` and I want to edit some values using their key.

Example:
Below we have a DATA table and I want to update the value of the key - "DDD" to 1

> ```
> AAA - "0"   
> BBB - "0" 
> CCC - "0' 
> DDD - "0"
> ```

How can this be done?

```
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In Dictionary1
    If i = value And kvp.Value <> "1" Then
        NewFlat = kvp.Key.ToString
        ---------------------------------------------
        I want to update set the Value 1 of respective key.
        What should I write here ? 
        ---------------------------------------------
        IsAdded = True
        Exit For
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next kvp
```

Comment: cant use the KeyValuePair its gives error after updating it as data get modified.

Comment: If you explain your exact conditions properly (inputs + what you want to get), I am sure that either Tim or I can deliver a code doing exactly what you want. Please, focus on one question and delete the other one and, next time, if your concerns are not properly addressed you should consider the option of asking (or explaining your question better) rather than posting a new question.

Answer (score 20):

If you know which kvp's value you want to change, you do not have to iterate (`for each kvp`) the dictionary to so.  to Change "DDD"/"0" to "DDD"/"1":

```
 myDict("DDD") = "1"
```

`cant use the KeyValuePair its gives error after updating it as data get modified.`

If you try to modify *any* collection in a `For Each` loop, you'll get a, `InvalidOperationException`.  The enumerator (the `For Each` variable) becomes invalid once the collection changes.  Especially with a Dictionary, this is not needed:

```
Dim col As New Dictionary(Of String, Int32)
col.Add("AAA", 0)
...
col.Add("ZZZ", 0)

Dim someItem = "BBB"
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Int32) In col
    If kvp.Key = someItem Then

        ' A) Change the value?
         vp.Value += 1          ' will not compile: Value is ReadOnly

        ' B) Update the collection?
        col(kvp.Key) += 1
    End If
Next
```

Method A wont compile because the `Key` and `Value` properties are ReadOnly.
Method B will change the count/Value, but result in the Exception on `Next` because `kvp` is no longer valid.

Dictionaries have a built in method to do all that for you:

```
If myDict.ContainsKey(searchKey) Then
    myDict(searchKey) = "1"
End If
```

Use the key to get/set/change/remove from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

There are times when you really do want to do something on each item in a dictionary. For example, I use dictionaries to store quite large structures of data, simply because it seems to be near instantaneous to grab my data from a huge heap, even when the dictionary appears to be 40MB of RAM.

For example:

```
dim col as new dictionary (of string, myStructData)

dim colKeys() as string = col.keys.toArray()
for each colKey in colKeys
  dim tempVal as new myStructData= col(colKey)
  'do whatever changes you want on tempVal
  col(colKey)=tempVal
next colKey
```

Because you are not changing what you're enumerating over, the exception is not thrown. Of course, if something else came along and messed up your data, then you'd either not iterate over everything, or you'd not find the key in the collection, depending on what had happenned. I only write this sort of thing for heavy processing on my own machine.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the problem of how to edit a value for a given key. It is how to edit all values given all keys.